# Select in a primary key interval SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

At school We saw you can select this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM BLALBLA
WHERE id=1 AND id = 2 AND id=3 AND id=4
```

But how can we do :

```
SELECT
FROM BLABLA
WHERE id = 1 to 4
```

Thank you
goldiman

Comment: Never thought, it's exist, thank you jarih :p

Comment: what you learned at school: how did it work? the id is 1 OR 2 but never can be 1 AND 2

Comment: have a look at the "operators" section here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: You right Thomas, I was not remembering correctly an element can't be selected the two ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM BLABLA WHERE id => 1 AND id =< 4
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways

1) if `id` field is integer.

```
SELECT *
FROM BLALBLA
WHERE id between 1 and 4

SELECT *
FROM BLALBLA
WHERE id => 1 AND id =< 4

SELECT *
FROM BLALBLA
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

2) if `id` is varchar

```
SELECT *
FROM BLALBLA
WHERE id IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Jarlh found the answer
"id between 1 and 4 –  jarlh 53 secs ago"
Thank you